# Error pushing ruby gem to rubygems.org

Tags: ruby

This is my first time pushing a ruby gem to rubygems.org, and I keep getting this message when I push the gem:

```
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EISDIR)                                                                                                 
Is a directory @ io_fread - tripadvisor-choice-cli-gem`
```

Any ideas? Let me know if I need to share anything else to shed light on the error. Thanks!

Comment: What command did you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must push a specific `.gem` file, not the directory in which the gem resides. That means in practice something like:

```
gem push my-gem-0.1.0.gem
```

Where that represents a very specific version of your gem. Normally you get that file from:

```
gem build my-gem.gemspec
```

Where that `.gemspec` file is either hand-authored or produced by some other process (e.g. `rake`).

Comment: It worked! Thanks, man. I couldn't find that anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: It's [in there](http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/) but there is a lot of other stuff that might've distracted from that section.